# Migrating vmnics to DVSwitch : Operation Timed Out

Tags: sync, vmware, time, esxi, vcenter

This setup is in Workstation version 16.1.0 build-17198959

vCenter version VMware-vCenter-Server-Appliance-6.7.0.45000-16708996_OVF10 (6.7 U3 J)

ESXi version VMware-VMvisor-Installer-201912001-15160138.x86_64

I'm facing an issue with vCenter timing out when adding vmnics to DVSwitch. The vmnics are not assigned to vSwitch. I create VMKernel adapters in DVswitch, then attach the vmnics to DVSwitch. I did the same for Management ports, and they worked fine. The moment I start the migration for the remaining vmnics, after sometime has passed vCenter shows as reconnecting https://i.ibb.co/19cXJgV/v-Center-Reconnecting.png.

The vpxd.log shows the following.

```
2021-05-05T13:42:45.149Z info vpxd[05049] [Originator@6876 sub=vpxLro opID=q-298:01-b8] [VpxLRO] -- BEGIN lro-3207 -- ResourceModel -- cis.data.provider.ResourceModel.query -- 52de6b05-ff57-5212-8e2f-2e5c30351224(520a6ec9-121f-c4c8-7aaa-cb0b0aa54c06)
2021-05-05T13:42:45.149Z info vpxd[05049] [Originator@6876 sub=vpxLro opID=q-298:01-b8] [VpxLRO] -- FINISH lro-3207
2021-05-05T13:42:45.150Z info vpxd[05049] [Originator@6876 sub=vpxLro opID=q-297:01-d0] [VpxLRO] -- BEGIN lro-3208 -- ResourceModel -- cis.data.provider.ResourceModel.query -- 52de6b05-ff57-5212-8e2f-2e5c30351224(520a6ec9-121f-c4c8-7aaa-cb0b0aa54c06)
2021-05-05T13:42:45.150Z info vpxd[05049] [Originator@6876 sub=vpxLro opID=q-297:01-d0] [VpxLRO] -- FINISH lro-3208
2021-05-05T13:42:45.160Z info vpxd[05003] [Originator@6876 sub=vpxLro opID=q-299:01-a1] [VpxLRO] -- BEGIN lro-3209 -- ResourceModel -- cis.data.provider.ResourceModel.query -- 52de6b05-ff57-5212-8e2f-2e5c30351224(520a6ec9-121f-c4c8-7aaa-cb0b0aa54c06)
2021-05-05T13:42:45.160Z info vpxd[05003] [Originator@6876 sub=vpxLro opID=q-299:01-a1] [VpxLRO] -- FINISH lro-3209
2021-05-05T13:42:45.594Z error vpxd[05738] [Originator@6876 sub=hostMethod] Commit call for method [updateNetworkConfig] transaction Id [17] failed on host [[vim.HostSystem:host-44,w-esx-vsn-01.vlab.lab]] with exception:[(vmodl.fault.SystemError) {
--> faultCause = (vmodl.MethodFault) null,
--> faultMessage = <unset>,
--> reason = "Transaction has rolled back on the host."
--> msg = "Received SOAP response fault from [<cs p:00007fb83c3d4020, TCP:w-esx-vsn-01.vlab.lab:443>]: commitTransaction
--> Received SOAP response fault from [<cs p:000000126b0b8950, TCP:localhost:8307>]: commitTransaction
--> A general system error occurred: Transaction has rolled back on the host."
--> }]
2021-05-05T13:42:45.595Z error vpxd[05734] [Originator@6876 sub=hostMethod] Commit call for method [updateNetworkConfig] transaction Id [15] failed on host [[vim.HostSystem:host-47,w-esx-vsn-02.vlab.lab]] with exception:[(vmodl.fault.SystemError) {
--> faultCause = (vmodl.MethodFault) null,
--> faultMessage = <unset>,
--> reason = "Transaction has rolled back on the host."
--> msg = "Received SOAP response fault from [<cs p:000055b41bcbab90, TCP:w-esx-vsn-02.vlab.lab:443>]: commitTransaction
--> Received SOAP response fault from [<cs p:0000002102452d90, TCP:localhost:8307>]: commitTransaction
--> A general system error occurred: Transaction has rolled back on the host."
--> }]
2021-05-05T13:42:45.605Z error vpxd[05077] [Originator@6876 sub=hostMethod] Commit call for method [updateNetworkConfig] transaction Id [16] failed on host [[vim.HostSystem:host-50,w-esx-vsn-03.vlab.lab]] with exception:[(vmodl.fault.SystemError) {
--> faultCause = (vmodl.MethodFault) null,
--> faultMessage = <unset>,
--> reason = "Transaction has rolled back on the host."
--> msg = "Received SOAP response fault from [<cs p:00007fb8344acf50, TCP:w-esx-vsn-03.vlab.lab:443>]: commitTransaction
--> Received SOAP response fault from [<cs p:0000003ff197bfb0, TCP:localhost:8307>]: commitTransaction
--> A general system error occurred: Transaction has rolled back on the host."
--> }]
2021-05-05T13:42:45.682Z info vpxd[05739] [Originator@6876 sub=vpxLro opID=q-301:h5ui-getProperties:urn:vmomi:DistributedVirtualPortgroup:dvportgroup-88:ddefdc78-bdea-43c9-8e4d-670bab2c3978:1364190193:01-4c] [VpxLRO] -- BEGIN lro-3210 -- ResourceModel -- cis.data.provider.ResourceModel.query -- 52de6b05-ff57-5212-8e2f-2e5c30351224(520a6ec9-121f-c4c8-7aaa-cb0b0aa54c06)
2021-05-05T13:42:45.683Z info vpxd[05739] [Originator@6876 sub=vpxLro opID=q-301:h5ui-getProperties:urn:vmomi:DistributedVirtualPortgroup:dvportgroup-88:ddefdc78-bdea-43c9-8e4d-670bab2c3978:1364190193:01-4c] [VpxLRO] -- FINISH lro-3210
```

Firewall has nothing blocked, all ports and protocols are open. I don't know if this is related to the NTP time sync issue I'm facing which is only affecting the vCenter Appliance, ESXi sync from the same firewall only that vCenter is 6 hours ahead while ESXi are syncing fine, not sure what is going on. I came to know this could be due to vCenter being part of a domain, my vCenter is not part of any domain, the ESXi are part of a Windows Domain.

vCenter NTP - https[://i.ibb.co/55CwkYC/v-Center-NTP.png](http://://i.ibb.co/55CwkYC/v-Center-NTP.png)

ESXi NTP - https://i.ibb.co/MpxgnRh/ESXiNTP.png

vCenter NTP Check - https://i.ibb.co/TrFfpc0/v-Center-NTPCheck.png

vCenter logging out evey now and then - https://i.ibb.co/Pz9gDBy/v-Center-Log-Out.png

Complete vxpd.log can be found here : https://mega.nz/folder/hpwz2ISQ#lEuR4AbcECRxBkhqmK7HqA

Comment: Just something I noticed, I'm able to assign vmnics to DVSwitch the 1st time I log into vCenter, and thats the only time I can move the vmnics once I try to move them after that they just time out, not sure whats causing this.

Comment: Anyone, anything ?